# How to separate two runtimes in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, runtime

There is a system that was compiled using one visual studio runtime(VS2013) and that system provides a api for develop external plugins for external developers. 
That external developers will use that api with different visual studio version(say VS2008). How to provide that api without having any runtimes issues.

I found that using a C API between two systems (main system and external plugin api) can separate the runtime issues.

Are there any better ways of doing that other that C API ?

Comment: There is no solution that i'm aware of that will work for all cases, compiler independent. You may want to consider static likage if you have access to the source code.

Comment: Yeh, Native C++ on Windows is not good at interoperability between versions of visual studio. For interoperability, choose C or C++/CLI (if .Net is an option for your external developers).

Comment: Also, this may interest you - http://siomsystems.com/mixing-visual-studio-versions/

Comment: You just have to code carefully.  Don't pass standard C++ library objects across the module boundary, don't allocate objects in one and destroy in another, don't throw exceptions.  The C language makes it easier to avoid shooting your leg off in the same way a ton of lead makes your car less likely to reach dangerous speeds.  The rules you'd apply when writing COM code is a good way to ensure you follow the rules.

Comment: All these problems have been solved 20 years ago. The technology to use is called [Component Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694363.aspx) (COM). Using COM allows you to implement consumers and producers of an API, using any runtime and any compiler (that supports COM).